# Как правильно реализовать на Qt интерфейс с вкладками и списками?

Tags: qt, qt5

Есть 4 вкладки. В каждой по списку. В зависимости от выбранного элемента списка справа должно меняться содержимое справа (формы, кнопки).

1) Я так понимаю на каждый заголовочный файл должно приходиться одно окно приложения? В каждом списке около 10 элементов. Итого 40 элементов в main.cpp?

2) В чем необходимо содержать формы? В каждом элементе списка 2.5 формы в среднем итого 100 форм.

3) Можно ли как-то каждую вкладку разбить по классам или что-то вроде того и как это будет выглядеть? Можно ли это реализовать на инструментарии QtQuick?

Comment: Опишите поподробнее зачем вам так, как вариант при нужном элементе списка программно генерировать новые элементы и задавать им нужного родителя.
Лично в моём приложении есть главный класс(ControlViewWidget), который инициирует главное окно и в него подгружает другие виджеты при определённых условия(при нужных сигналах).
Если нужно, могу приложить исходники тестового проекта.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко было бы интересно посмотреть как это реализовано. Я не совсем понимаю как можно сэкономить время и не расписывать 100 форм. У меня некоторые формы совпадают. Только регулярные выражения для них должны быть разными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтож, мой пост почему-то не подошёл местной модерации, постараюсь исправиться. Отвечу на ваши вопросы по порядку:

1. Нет, Своё окно виджет будет иметь только если не задать ему родителя.
2. Некорректный вопрос, ответить не могу. Если вы подразумеваете под формой Класс формы Qt Designer то, как обычно в связке h+cpp+ui.
3. Каждая вкладка `TabWidget` это отдельный `QWidget`. Ответил вроде так, как понимаю, если что поправьте.

Сделал шаблонное приложение, залил на гитхаб https://github.com/fenixrus/MoreWindowApplication

Comment: Многое стало понятно, спасибо. Но мне интересно как сэкономить на коде ведь например в коде практически идентичные secondwidget и thirdwidget. Не придумано ли что-то в Qt для однообразных виджетов?

Comment: А что мешает сделать один "шаблонный класс форм" и в его методах, либо в конструкторе задавать нужные параметры, нужный вывод, и таких сколько угодно можно классов инициализировать.